# conda list returning run-time error Path not Found after installing PyTortch

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, pytorch

Recently I tried to install Pytrotch using the command
    `conda install pytorch torchvision cuda100 -c pytorch`

To verity the package installed correctly I ran `conda list` in the anaconda prompt and got the following error:

`RuntimeError: Path not found: C:\Users\[name]\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\Sphinx-1.5.6-py3.6.egg\EGG-INFO`

I'm currently running conda version 4.6.1 and python version 3.6.7 on windows 10, I'd appreciate any  help in determining what caused this error and how it can be fixed so I can properly manage my anaconda packages.

Full stack trace:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\[name]\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1001, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\[name]\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 84, in _main
        exit_code = do_call(args, p)
      File "C:\Users\[name]\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 81, in do_call
        exit_code = getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
      File "C:\Users\[name]\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_list.py", line 142, in execute
        show_channel_urls=context.show_channel_urls)
      File "C:\Users\[name]\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_list.py", line 80, in print_packages
        show_channel_urls=show_channel_urls)
      File "C:\Users\[name]\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_list.py", line 45, in list_packages
        installed = sorted(PrefixData(prefix, pip_interop_enabled=True).iter_records(),
      File "C:\Users\[name]\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\prefix_data.py", line 116, in iter_records
        return itervalues(self._prefix_records)
      File "C:\Users\[name]\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\prefix_data.py", line 145, in _prefix_records
        return self.__prefix_records or self.load() or self.__prefix_records
      File "C:\Users\[name]\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\prefix_data.py", line 69, in load
        self._load_site_packages()
      File "C:\Users\[name]\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\prefix_data.py", line 258, in _load_site_packages
        python_record = read_python_record(self.prefix_path, af, python_pkg_record.version)
      File "C:\Users\[name]\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\disk\read.py", line 245, in read_python_record
        pydist = PythonDistribution.init(prefix_path, anchor_file, python_version)
      File "C:\Users\[name]\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\pkg_formats\python.py", line 90, in init
        return PythonEggInfoDistribution(anchor_full_path, python_version, sp_reference)
      File "C:\Users\[name]\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\pkg_formats\python.py", line 400, in __init__
        super(PythonEggInfoDistribution, self).__init__(anchor_full_path, python_version)
      File "C:\Users\[name]\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\pkg_formats\python.py", line 104, in __init__
        raise RuntimeError("Path not found: %s" % anchor_full_path)
    RuntimeError: Path not found: C:\Users\[name]\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\Sphinx-1.5.6-py3.6.egg\EGG-INFO`

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8156 This might help you!

Comment: thanks @P.Antoniadis this is definitely relevant! Is the solution then to go through environment directories and remove those references?

Comment: Yes, this is the only way cause the issue is still in progress. If this doesn't fix the problem, try downgrading anaconda and wait until the issue is fixed.

Comment: rm -rf ~/Anaconda3/Lib/site-packagesSphinx-1.5.1-py3.6.egg/ fixed it for me

Answer (score 1):

AS @P.Antoniadis said, this is an ongoing issue. And removing 'Sphinx-1.5.6-py3.6.egg' folder is the suggested workaround.

https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8156#issuecomment-458777849